# Moving a specific file from a list every week, from one folder to another in Google Scripts

Tags: automation, calendar, schedule

I'm new to Google Apps Scripts. I managed to build a series of scripts to zip and attach files from a folder in Google Drive and sent them by email on a weekly basis. Some of these files to be zipped+attached will be added manually (because they'll be created+added every week) by some people), but other files were already created by its authors in advance (however, only 1 file per author is needed every week).
Regarding these files already created -but not needing more than 1 every week-, I'm wondering if there's a way to schedule an automatic moving of 1 specific file from a list (located in a folder belonging to an author) to the folder involved in the "zip+attach+email" script. An ideal way for this would be moving 1 file per week, sorting by creation date or file name. Example:
For a list containing these documents in FolderA:
Doc1
Doc2
Doc3

The script should do this action to move 1 file to FolderB:
Week 1: move only Doc1 from FolderA to Folder B
Week 2: move only Doc2 from FolderA to Folder B
Week 3: move only Doc3 from FolderA to Folder B

I managed to build the basic code lines to move files from one folder to another (using folder IDs)...

```
function moveDocFiles(moveFromFolderId, moveToFolderId) {
  var moveFrom = DriveApp.getFolderById('FROM THIS GOOGLE DRIVE FOLDER ID');
  var moveTo = DriveApp.getFolderById('TO THIS GOOGLE DRIVE FOLDER ID');
```

... but I'm still struggling to create a schedule as described above (I tried to find other examples of code to do this automation, but I was unable to find this specific action).
Can anyone please give me some guidance over this issue?
Thank you in advance!